# Create new bitmap with black remain region issue

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have to create new bitmap from an original image after user do somethings with it like zooming, rotating, dragging. And i have a frame border, and only part of original image lay on frame is picked. Issue is that remain region of frame is black, and i want it could be transparent or white. How to do that? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

```
public Bitmap createBitmap(final Matrix pMatrix, final Bitmap pSourceBitmap){

  Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, pSourceBitmap.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
  canvas.drawBitmap(pSourceBitmap, pMatrix, new Paint());

  return bmp;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the remaining portion transparent

use the following code

```
public Bitmap createBitmap(final Matrix pMatrix, final Bitmap pSourceBitmap)
{
     Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
     Bitmap bmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf); 
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
     canvas.drawBitmap(pSourceBitmap, pMatrix, new Paint());

     return bmp;
}
```